# Congruence equation system

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

The system is in $Z_3$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2a+b+2c=1 \\ 
2d+e=1 \\ 
a+e=2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

My attempt:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$R_3 <-> R_2$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$R_2 -> 3R_2$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$R_1 -> 2R_1$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

At this point I don't know what to do.

$R$ stands for "line" of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $-2$ and adding to the last we get
$$-2b-4c+e=-1$$
and also is 
$$2d+e=1$$
can you finish?

Comment: I have to solve it using matrices